# i can't free binary tree correctly, how could i debug it?

Tags: c, binary-tree, valgrind, free

I got a binary tree playing the game to guess the user's guess.
All worked fine until I tried to free the binary tree.
I used the valgrind to check, they give me these:

```
==8205== Invalid read of size 8
==8205==    at 0x400F0A: treePrint (in /home/mbax4nc2/COMP26120/ex6/pangolin)
==8205==    by 0x400A14: main (in /home/mbax4nc2/COMP26120/ex6/pangolin)
==8205==  Address 0x4c334a8 is 200 bytes inside a block of size 216 free'd
==8205==    at 0x4A06430: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:446)
==8205==    by 0x400DEE: freeTree (in /home/mbax4nc2/COMP26120/ex6/pangolin)
==8205==    by 0x400A08: main (in /home/mbax4nc2/COMP26120/ex6/pangolin)

typedef struct node{
    char name[100];
    char question[100];
    struct node *yes;
    struct node *no;
}node;

void freeTree(node *root)
{ //Tree's root note is passed as argument
  if (root == NULL)
  {
    return;
  }

  if (root->no != NULL)
  {
    freeTree(root->no);
    root->no = NULL;
  }

  if (root->yes != NULL)
  {
    freeTree(root->yes);
    root->yes = NULL;
  }

  free(root);

  return;
}
```

I didn't paste all my program in here, because it was really a long version. What's wrong with my free() function? How could I debug it? I didn't know how to use the valgrind record to fix my program.

Comment: nothing, valgrind said that you access freed memory in the function `treePrint`.

Comment: Then how could i detect where is wrong? @mch

Comment: Compile with symbols (and line numbers). Option `-g` for GCC.

Comment: do you call `treePrint` after `freeTree`?

Comment: @mch Yes..I just want to make sure all is free...Can't i do that??

Comment: @alk Isn't supposed to be -v??

Comment: No, `-v` is for "*be verbose*".

Comment: @mch It really helped me correct some errors after i deleted the treePrint()..But it still said that :   total heap usage: 12 allocs, 11 frees, 3,296 bytes allocated..How could I find the one that hadn't been freed??

Comment: @alk I tried, but it responded that "valgrind: Bad option: -g"

Comment: Ì wrote to **compile** with symbols (...). `-g` is an option to the compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To debug dynamic memory management: Count all calls to `malloc()`, `calloc()`, `realloc(NULL, ...)` and `strdup()`, sum them up and then count all calls to `free()`, excluding calls to `free(NULL)`. The former and the later count shall match, if the don't you found a bug.

Just as a note: If the two counts mentioned above match, this does *not* mean memory management is done *correctly*.

Answer (score 1):

just simple as this:

```
void freeTree(node *root)
{ 
    if (!root )
        return;

    freeTree(root->no);
    freeTree(root->yes);
    free(root);
    return;
}
```

Comment: In essence this isn't different from the OPs code, is it?

Comment: @alk, no it is not. but it just make code clearer, and confirms that `freetree ` is good, of course this if he is using alloc or calloc to allocate memory for the nodes

Comment: @alk, :)  ... you asked `is it` i said `no` it is not deferent from the OPs code.

Comment: Yes, it just took me some time to understand this. However strictly spoken you should have answered "*yes*", as in "*Yes, there is no difference.*" ;-)

Comment: This should probably be an edit to the question instead of an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the error may have been caused not by the free function but somewhere else in the code.  Your free function looks ok to me even though it could be simpler like in milevyo's answer.  If I had to guess I would say that you are not correctly initializing the yes and no pointers to null.  By default they will point to some invalid memory.  You need to set them to null any time you add a new node.  It would help if you posted the rest of the code.

Actually I just looked at the comments and you said you called print after calling free.  This should work so long as you set the root node to null after calling freeTree (assuming your print function correctly handles empty null trees).  I notice that this function will not change the root node even though it frees it.  The free function does not change the value of a pointer and that pointer will still point to the same location.  I always set pointers to null after freeing them just to be safe.